# How to re-initialize an llvm::GlobalVariable

Tags: c++, c++11, llvm, llvm-ir

I 'm trying to create a function in llvm IR which re-assigns all **llvm::GlobalVariable** to their initial values.

I tried to tackle the problem by first iterating over all **llvm::GlobalVariable** of an **llvm::Module** and then, for each **llvm::GlobalVariable** which has an initializer and isn't a constant, to add to my new function an **llvm::StoreInst** which will perform the assignment.

My problem is that **llvm::GlobalVariable::getInitializer()** returns an  ***llvm::Constant** which is a base class and I am unsure of how to get access to the initialization values especially for custom structs and classes. Should I use some sort of downcasting or is there any cleaner solution ?

This is my code so far which compiles well but crashes on runtime:  (*Assertion `getOperand(1)->getType()->isPointerTy() && "Ptr must have pointer type!"' failed.*)

```
Module::GlobalListType* glist = &M.getGlobalList();

for(auto it=glist->begin(); it!=glist->end(); ++it){

  if(it->hasInitializer() && !it->isConstant()){
    Constant* con = it->getInitializer();
    StoreInst(it, con, RET);//RET is a pointer to an existing instruction.
  }

}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: one problem i am seeing is as per http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StoreInst.html   StoreInst (Value *Val, Value *Ptr, Instruction *InsertBefore) takes first argument the value and second is pointer, did you try StoreInst(con, it, RET); instead of StoreInst(it, con, RET);?

Comment: You can also look into it->setInitializer(Constant*);

Comment: I believe that is StoreInst(con, it, RET);

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! Replacing StoreInst(it, con, RET) with StoreInst(con, it, RET) solved it!

Thanks so much !